# ROS Answers SE migration: rosbag slow?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I'm using ROS with two machines on wireless network.
Let say, machine #1,#2.

The machine #1 has USB camera, and running roscore.
The machine #2 is for viewing /usb_cam/image_raw/compressed, and recording video using rosbag.

Before run rosbag recording, everything is fine. However, when I ran the rosbag, both machine become very slow and about after 30secs later, the video is stucked.

Does anyone have experienced this problem?

To record using rosbag, I have used following command.

$ rosbag record

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35229/rosbag-slow?/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The (likely) problem here is that ROS uses peer-to-peer transport, so adding a second subscriber (the rosbag) doubles the number of bits that need to get pushed over your wireless link.

You can use a [republish node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport#republish) to solve this; run it on machine #2, and then run the viewer and rosbag record on machine #2, but subscribed to the republish node, not the actual data topic. Then you move the bits over the wireless link once (machine #1 -> republish node), and then twice on the loopback interface (republish -> viewer and republish -> rosbag).

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3